# ¿Cómo uso una variable que contiene un enlace ubicada en un componente cliente en el resto de componentes sean o no clientes en Next.js 13?

Tags: fetch, next.js, nextjs, nextjs13

Veran estoy haciendo un proyecto, el cual en resumen de mi problema, debo tener una interfaz donde se ingresara en un input el enlace donde se encuentra montado una API de terceros que usare, en resumen yo solo me encargo de conectar y crud desde la web, mandando y recibiendo Json de la API. Al presionar un boton se hara un fetch para validar que reciba un response 200. Si es asi, dicho valor del input se va a guardar en una variable que se encuentra en el componente que llame "enlace.jsx", El cual posee el siguiente codigo:

```
"use client"
// Este archivo permite acceder a una variable que va a contener
// el enlace del servidor donde corre nuestra API.

// Valor por defecto VACIO, solo se usa para consultar como programador.
export let enlace = "VACIO";

export const setEnlace = (newUrl) => {
  enlace = newUrl;
};
```

Debe ser la variable let, ya que sino no me deja modificarla luego, y el setEnlace me permite actualizarla. Es de tipo cliente para que el usuario al ingresar el input lo pueda modificar.

Ahora en mi otro archivo el cual deseo simplemente hacer un fetch con el enlace que guarde mas una direccion con el endpoint a ejecutar. El codigo es:

```
import { ListaUsuarios } from "@/app/components/ListaUsuarios";
import {enlace} from '@/app/components/Enlace'

async function fetchUsers(){
    const response = await fetch(enlace + "/testAPI/api/productos").then((res) => res.json());

    return response;
}

export async function UsersFetch() {

    const users = await fetchUsers();

    return(
        <ListaUsuarios users={users}></ListaUsuarios>
    );    
}
```

Por ultimo, no le hagan caso sobre que diga en algunos lugares productos o en otros users, no actualice los nombres iguales pero es indiferente en esta etapa de pruebas. Ese ListaUsuarios es un map que se encarga de recorrer el Json y mostrar los datos. El codigo es:

```
export async function ListaUsuarios({ users }) {
    return (
            <ul>
                {
                    users.map((user) => (
                        <li key={user.id}>
                            <div>
                                <h5>{user.id}  {user.nombre}  {user.apellido} {user.correo}</h5>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    ))
                }
            </ul>
    );   
}
```

Necesito que la variable no sea "VACIA" al llegar a el archivo de UsersFetch, y si le coloco el tipo "use client" me devuelve un error que no entiendo el porque: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON.

Pero si pongo el enlace completo en el fetch sin usar la variable si me funciona a la perfeccion.

Ayuda por favor, necesito saber como solucionar esto. Si pudieran un ejemplo con codigo, modificando el mio, me funcionaria mucho. O una explicacion. Entiendo que tiene que ver con que las paginas la mayoria se cargan del lado del servidor y no del cliente, pero no se como solucionar o adaptar entonces mi situacion...

Gracias